# Reescrita de URL com sinal de "+" (igual Google+) .htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess, url, url-amigável, mod-rewrite

Gostaria de escrever uma regra no .htaccess com o RewriteRule usando o sinal de mais (+) para uma url no formato parecido com o Google, assim:

**meusite.com.br/+alguem** fosse interpretado **meusite.com.br/?track=alguem**
ou
**meusite.com.br/umapagina+alguem** fosse interpretado **meusite.com.br/umapagina?track=alguem**

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\+(.*)$ /?track=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1?track=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Amigo se eu pudesse dava 1000 estrelas pela resposta. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: De nada. O importante é que funcionou. Basicamente é apenas uma expressão regular.

Comment: Diego, poderia me ajudar com essa outra questão por favor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98431/reescrita-de-url-com-par%c3%a2metro-para-outro-site-htaccess