# Reescrita de URL com parâmetro para outro site .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, redirecionamento, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Gostaria de escrever uma regra no `.htaccess` com o `RewriteRule` de forma que quando alguém entrar no site antigo, seja redirecionado para o site novo mantendo o parâmetro solicitado no site antigo.

**Site antigo:**

```
velhosite.com.br/?people=alguem
velhosite.com.br/uma-pagina-qualquer?people=alguem
```

**Redirecionado para o novo:**

```
novosite.com.br/?pessoa=alguem
novosite.com.br/uma-pagina-qualquer?pessoa=alguem
```

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para redirecionamento costumo utilizar para o 301:

```
Redirect 301 ^(www.)?velhosite\.com\.br/?people=alguem$  http://novosite.com.br/?pessoa=alguem
Redirect 301 ^(www.)?velhosite\.com\.br/uma-pagina-qualquer?people=alguem$  http://novosite.com.br/uma-pagina-qualquer?pessoa=alguem
```

Mas você pode apontar toda a estrutura do site da raiz para um subdomínio por exemplo, e a partir de lá você faz os redirecionamentos que precisa:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://novosite.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Também pode fazer uma condição, para um determinado domínio:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?velhosite\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://novosite.com.br/novo-layout/ [R=301,L]
```

Para cada regra de substituição, você coloca na ordem:

exemplo de regra: `^pagina.php?a=(.*)&b=([0-9])&c=([a-z])$`, pode ser representado por: `/a/$1/b/$2/c/$3` ou `/a-$1/b-$2/c-$3` ou `$1/$2/$3` ou `$1-$2-$3` ou `a=$1&b=$2&c=$3`

Você também pode modificar a ordem, exemplo: `/c/$3/b/$2/a/$1`.
O que faz a regra ser reconhecida é a url digitada no navegador, será interpretada e acionar o link original (a regra) no lado servidor.

```
Redirect 301 ^(www.)?velhosite\.com\.br/?people=(.*)$  http://novosite.com.br/?pessoa=$1
Redirect 301 ^(www.)?velhosite\.com\.br/(.+)?people=(.*)$  http://novosite.com.br/$1?pessoa=$2
```

Veja mais informações sobre regras na [**documentação do apache**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Amigo, uma outra duvida usando o primeiro principio que falou onde tem "alguem" varia por nome de usuário preciso passar o usuário para o outro site e em "uma-pagina-qualquer" é a mesma coisa são várias paginas como fazer enviar isso? O site velho continua ativo só quero redirecionar quem entrar via "?eople=alguem" entende? Me ajuda nessa... obrigadão...

Comment: Editei lá @MüllerNato, veja se deu pra entender. Só ressaltando que dependendo da flag, ou da regra, ela obriga que tudo seja digitado para que haja mudanças.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Müller Nato.

Creio que o que você precise seja a Flag QSA, Query String Append.
Ela faz nada mais que adicionar a query string, que a parte da URL que vem depois de ?, inclusive, ao final da url reescrita. Por exemplo: ?full=bar&bar=full

Para fazer com que a query string seja repassada à tua URL reescrita, basta que adiciones esta flag.
Por exemplo:

dominio_antigo.conf

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://novosite.com.br$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

`R` -> Flag de Redirect, `301` Código HTTP de redirecionamento permanente.

`QSA` -> Incluir a query string na url reescrita.

`L`     -> Last. Significa que se esta regra for processada, as seguintes serão ignoradas.

Agora que o novo domínio já recebeu a url reescrita você reescreve a url recebida para que adeque à suas regras, assim:

dominio_novo.conf

```
#?people=alguem
#/?pessoa=alguem
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^people=(.*) /?pessoa=$1 [L]

#/uma-pagina-qualquer?people=alguem
#/uma-pagina-qualquer?pessoa=alguem
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?people=(.*) /$1?pessoa=$2 [L]
```

Fonte: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Até dá pra escrever uma regra só pra rescrever qualquer tipo de url, mas aí tem que pensar melhor na expressão regular.

Comment: @Müller Nato Outra coisa, veja que resposta legal que eu achei, ela explica um pouco mais as flags, depois você dá uma lida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86900/6660